# GKComponentSystem in Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, gameplay-kit

I'm having trouble converting my project to Swift 3. In previous version of Swift I can declare a class under GKComponentSystem like:

```
class EnemyMoveComponentSystem: GKComponentSystem {
}
```

However in swift 3 it forces me to add < GKComponent > in the end as:

```
class EnemyMoveComponentSystem: GKComponentSystem <GKComponent> {
    func updateWithDeltaTime(seconds: TimeInterval, gameScene: GameScene) {
        for component in components {
            print("something")
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that I can't access each individual component within the system like before

```
for component in components {
     print("something")   
}
```

The line print("something") was never triggered.
How can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was. I forgot to link the entity to the component system.
.addComponent(foundIn: Entity)